# Why Embarcadero RAD Studio XE5 can't find my phone?

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, delphi-xe5, android-sdk-tools

I have installed Embarcadero RAD Studio XE5 and try to test my first application on my phonу, but RAD studio cant find it in "Target". How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you follow the instructions in Embarcadero's documentation:

[Configuring Your System to Detect Your Android Device](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Configuring_Your_System_to_Detect_Your_Android_Device)

The IDE relies on the [Android Debugger Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to communicate with devices and simulators.  If ADB does not recognize your device, neither will the IDE.